# Spark SQL: Transforming some rows into columns

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to transform a `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` like this

```
Predictor  icaoCode  num1  num2
P1         OTHH       1.1   1.2
P1         ZGGG       2.1   2.2
P2         OTHH       3.1   3.2
P2         ZGGG       4.1   4.2
P3         OTHH       5.1   5.2
P3         ZGGG       6.1   6.2
.           .          .     .
.           .          .     .
.           .          .     .
```

into a `DataFrame` like this?

```
icaoCode  P1.num1  P1.num2  P2.num1  P2.num2  P3.num1  P3.num2  ...
OTHH          1.1      1.2      3.1      3.2      5.1      5.2  ...
ZGGG          2.1      2.2      4.1      4.2      6.1      6.2  ...
 .             .        .        .        .        .        .   ...    
 .             .        .        .        .        .        .   ...    
 .             .        .        .        .        .        .   ...
```

There can be an arbitrary number of values for `Predictor` and for `icaoCode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **Spark 1.6.0**, there is a [`pivot` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData) to transform/transpose your data. In your case it requires some preprocessing to get the data ready for `pivot`. Here an example how I'd do it:

```scala
def doPivot(): Unit = {
  val sqlContext: SQLContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

  // dummy data
  val r1 = Input("P1", "OTHH", 1.1, 1.2)
  val r2 = Input("P1", "ZGGG", 2.1, 2.2)
  val r3 = Input("P2", "OTHH", 3.1, 3.2)

  val records = Seq(r1, r2, r3)
  val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(records)

  // prepare data for pivot
  val fullName: ((String, String) => String) = (predictor: String, num: String) => {
    predictor + "." + num
  }
  val udfFullName = udf(fullName)
  val dfFullName = df.withColumn("num1-complete", udfFullName(col("predictor"), lit("num1")))
    .withColumn("num2-complete", udfFullName(col("predictor"), lit("num2")))

  val dfPrepared = dfFullName.select(col("icaoCode"), col("num1") as "num", col("num1-complete") as "value")
    .unionAll(dfFullName.select(col("icaoCode"), col("num2") as "num", col("num2-complete") as "value"))

  // transpose/pivot dataframe
  val dfPivoted = dfPrepared.groupBy(col("icaoCode")).pivot("value").mean("num")
  dfPivoted.show()
}

case class Input(predictor: String, icaoCode: String, num1: Double, num2: Double)
```

The final dataframe should work for you:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|icaoCode|P1.num1|P1.num2|P2.num1|P2.num2|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    OTHH|    1.1|    1.2|    3.1|    3.2|
|    ZGGG|    2.1|    2.2|   null|   null|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```